# Removing fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

When i try to remove the fragment, the if check is not working correctly 
My code is

```
public void onClick(View v) {
switch (v.getId()) {
case R.id.vehicle_button:

if(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.relative_tread_fragment).isVisible()){

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.relative_tread_fragment)).commit();
}
flag = true;
break;

case R.id.trailer_button:
flag = false;
break;

case R.id.button_search:

if (VRN.contains(actv.getText().toString()) && flag == true) {
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.relative_tread_fragment, fragment1).commit();
}
else if (VRN.contains(actv.getText().toString()) && flag == false) 
{
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.relative_tread_fragment, fragment2).commit();
}
else {
flag = true;
Custom_Dialog(v);
}
```

i am trying to remove if any fragment is already present,
but if there is no fragment, then that ***if block*** which checks if any fragment is there doesn't work and the app tries to remove the fragment which is not there and the app crashes

any suggestions how i should chk if there is a fragment or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to check whether a certain fragment is inside a certain holder layout:

```
Fragment yourFrag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.yourFragmentHolderView);
        return yourFrag != null && yourFrag instanceof whateverFragment;
```

You can then use methods like isVisible() etc on that fragment and remove it if you want to!.

So for example, I have an Activity which contains an inbox OR outbox fragment. If I want to know which one is active I use one of the following methods:

```
public boolean checkIsInbox() {
        Fragment inboxFrag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(LIST_FRAG_HOLDER_ID);
        return inboxFrag != null && inboxFrag instanceof InboxListFragment;
    }

    public boolean checkIsOutbox() {
        Fragment outboxFrag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(LIST_FRAG_HOLDER_ID);
        return outboxFrag != null && outboxFrag instanceof OutboxListFragment;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can you should use replace instead of remove. If you want to remove all fragments then just empty the back stack like:

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

- create a Boolean type global variable
- use that variable to check if the fragment is visible or not e.g.

  - set boolean variable to true, fragment is visible
  - else variable is false, fragment is hidden.